# Authentication between different applications through sessions (React + Express)?

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication, session

I'm developing a React + Express website and I'm in doubt on how to implement the login functionality since it depends on another application. Let me explain it:

- There is a system (app 1) in which the users create their accounts
- Once the user is logged into the system, they can click a button that redirects them to the website
- When the button is clicked inside the system (app 1), it makes a POST request to the backend of the website (app 2), sending the encrypted user credentials to the endpoint

I managed to get the posted data from the system in the website's backend, but now I'm not sure on how to pass/get this data into the frontend. I'm thinking on doing it like so:

- Once the backend (app 2) receives the user data from the system (app 1), it creates a session that witholds the user data (still encrypted)
- With the session created, the backend redirects to the frontend (app 3)
- The frontend (app 3) makes a request to the backend (app 2) to get the needed data that is stored in the session (basically the user name)

I'm new on the backend topic so, although I think this method will work, I'm not sure if it's a good way.

I appreciate whoever can contribute with feedback and ideas and I'm open to provide more information if necessary.

Comment: The client usually has to hold a token whether in a cookie or saved in localStorage, that has to be appended to the headers as a bearer token, and that identifies a request as authneticated, otherwise how do you know if the user that logged into the system is the same that is browsing your website ?

Comment: Hi, @CesarePolonara! Ok, so the token should be genereted by the system and sent to the website's backend on the header of the POST request? Or it should be generated on the website's backend when it receives the POST request from the system? How do I pass it to the frontend/client?

Comment: Not sure what this "system" is, but you can manage all on your backend, as long as you receive the login data by the "system". Try to check this: https://codeforgeek.com/refresh-token-jwt-nodejs-authentication/

Comment: The system is just another application, separeted from the website. I'll check the article that you shared, thank's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From trying to apply @Dylan suggestions, I kept searching and understood that I was looking at things from the wrong perspective. I was thinking about my frontend and backend as two separate things.

My backend was running on port 5000 and the frontend on port 3000, so wehenever I tried to pass some authorization header or cookies from my backend to my frontend, they were wiped since the domain was changing.

The socket.io approach also didn't work because I didn't have "app 1" and "app 3" opened at the same time in diferent places (I'm sure that probably there is a way to do it with socket.io, but I didn't menaged to).

So, once I wrapped my head aroud those basic concepts of HTTP requests, the first thing I did was to run the website's both front and backend at the same port (I'll share the tutorial here once I find it). With this I then could pass tokens and cookies from back to front and vice versa.

Ultimately I rebuild my website in Next.js and used cookies to persist the login!

Answer (score 0):

When creating your user backend you can create an `auth` router that is responsible for signing users in and creating users.

```
authRouter.post('/signup', async (req, res, next) => {
  const { username, email, password: plainTextPassword } = req.body;
```

Then when creating the login/signup you would create a `token` that stores all of the user information inside a combination of letters and numbers. This is created by a package called [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken). An example would be the following:

```
const newUser = await User.create(user)

token = jwt.sign(
  {
     _id: newUser._id,
     username: newUser.username,
     email: newUser.email,
     type: 'user',
  },
  process.env.SECRET,
  { expiresIn: '24h' }
);
return res.status(201).send({ token, newUser })
```

note I **did not** send their password.

then when you receive the response, i'm assuming you're using axios, you can set the token in `localStorage`.

```
const storeUser = ({ userObj: user, token }) => {
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
};

const login = (credentials) => {
   axios
      .post('/auth/login', credentials)
      .then((response) => {
        storeUser(response.data);
      }.catch (error) { console.error(error) }
}
```

Thats the basics of it. look into [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) and if you're looking for something extra for security [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) for securing passwords.

From what you have described, you should be able to do all of the above with one extra step, look into [socket.io](https://socket.io/) that should get you started in implementing what I just described but with two applications, they just need to be able to communicate. Just create the token then send it to your second application. Socket.io is your solution.

Comment: Hi Dylan! For what I got from your answer, You're assuming all the registration/user db handleing is beign made by my website's backend, right? In this case, I see how it would work since my frontend would do a request to my backend, the backend would then respond with the token and the frontend would get it directly. The problem is it is not my case.

Comment: I have an application (app 1) that witholds the users and this app makes a POST request to my website's backend (app 2), and the response to this request has to go to another application (app3: the client side of the website). It would be like logging to a site/app trought Facebook /Google account, for example.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Check out the last bit. @jbmgil_vlrzz

Comment: Hi @Dylan! I was studying a little bit about socket.io and, in theory, It really seems to be able to solve my problems, but I'm not getting on how to apply it. I have a server.js with `app.use("/login", require("./routes/loginRoute"));`. In loginRoute.js I have `router.post('/', logUser);`. And in loginController.js I have the logUser function to handle the login.

Comment: I imagine that once in the controller, the server should generate the token and load a frontend page in the browser sending the token.

Comment: the way socket.io works is it allows a connection between server and client where the client is listening for a response, normally you would send a request from the client and expect a response but instead you don't need to send a request, so in your case on app 3 you would just be listening for a new token, when it's received then the user is allowed access to your content.

Comment: Hi @Dylan! Sorry that I vanished from here... I switched projects and ended up forgetting about this topic. I'd like to thank for your help! Your suggestions guided me to learning the right things to solve my problem.